# WPF set Grid row tooltip

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I have a Grid in which I have a RichTextBox control for the description text and there is a ToolTip attached with that RichTextBox. Please check the below code-

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" >
         <controls:RichTextBox Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="False" />                          

         <Grid.ToolTip>
               <ToolTip>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Descriptiontext}"  
                         TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </ToolTip>
         </Grid.ToolTip>
</Grid>
```

And I wanted to set "ToolTipService.ShowDuration" property for ToolTip. But I am not getting a way, where to attach it.

Can anyone suggest how we can do that.

Answer (score 2):

The ShowDuration property is actually an attached property from the contained TooltipService. You can put it either on the ToolTip itself or the parent Grid. i.e.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="5000">
     <controls:RichTextBox Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="False" />                          

     <Grid.ToolTip>
           <ToolTip>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Descriptiontext}"  
                     TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </ToolTip>
     </Grid.ToolTip>
</Grid>
```